# How to select the total number of entries in a column which begin with 5 digits and a space with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, count, where-clause

How to get the total number of entries in a column which begin with 5 digits and a space with PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a regex match?

```sql
select count(*) from mytable where col ~ '^\d{5}\s'
```

`col` is the name of the column that you want to filter on. The regex breakdowns as follows:

```
^        beginning of the string
\d{5}    five digits
\s       one space
```